# CSS calc() written in different way

Tags: css, minify, css-calc

I'm having issues with the CSS `calc()` function and CSS minifier. In my source .css file, I have variable

```
margin-left: calc(15px - 20%);
```

However, when the source file is translated with the minifier, I get the output

```
margin-left: calc(-20%+15px);
```

And that value cannot be read properly in the web browser - all I can see in Chrome dev options is <s>margin-left: calc(-20%+15px);</s>, with the warning sign next to it saying "Invalid property value".

How can I avoid that, maybe write calc() function in different way to fix this issue? Changing places of variables in the source .css files doesn't make any changes, and I don't have an option to use different minifier.

Comment: And what minifier are you using? If relevant add to the question

Comment: Would depend on the minifier you are using and if it has settings for how it parses the calc function

Comment: try using something like this calc(~"15px - 20%");

Comment: Minifier is, at least for now unknown and it's setting cannot be changed. We use it over an remote interface and nobody in our team doesn't know anything about it. We should use it the way we have it, changing it is the last option.

Comment: This is the source of the problem so… You could try replacing space by a non-breaking space (&nbsp; but not as is, as " " aka Alt+0160 on Windows and (compose key + space + space) with WinCompose software for example) in hope minifier won't minify all whitespace. If minifier is too old or too buggy to handle calc() correctly, you're out of luck.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but unfortunately nothing works out of those solutions, browser still cannot read them properly. Is there any way to write calc() function as a combination of multiple divs and their parameters?

Comment: can you share the use case of this value? we can then try to find another way to achieve the same without calc

Comment: @TemaniAfif I have one div with content about user. Under that, I'm trying to position a map (Google Map), and its start should be at (-20% + 15) of user content width (in other words, a bit left from user content). Width of the map is also calculated dinamically, as width: calc(145% - 55px); Width is working correctly, I guess that minifier has problems with reading the negative percentage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to write it this way:

```css
.box {
 margin-left: calc(-1*calc(20% - 15px));
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```